# ArduinoでRCOSCモードに変更・TCXOを切断するには？

Tags: spresense

DeepSleep中に待機電力を少なくするために下記を行いたいと思っております。
検索したところ、以下のような記述を見つけました。

[SPRESENSEと他のプラットフォームの消費電力 | SPRESENSEの消費電力を可視化して解析](https://www.aps-web.jp/academy/amp/10632/#SPRESENSE)

> Deep-Sleepへ遷移する前に「CPUクロックをRCOSCモードに変更（HVモード、LVモードのロックを解除）」し「TCXOを切断（board_xtal_power_control(false)）」の設定を行うことにより、Deep-Sleep中の消費電力を大きく削減することができます。

これをArduinoで実行するためにはどのようにすればよいでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

Arduinoからでも次のようなコードで実行できます（できました）。

```c
#include <LowPower.h>
#include <arch/board/board.h> // 追加

void setup() {
  // LowPowerライブラリの初期化
  LowPower.begin();

  // CPUクロックをRCOSCモードに変更
  LowPower.clockMode(CLOCK_MODE_8MHz);
  
  // TCXOの電源OFF
  board_xtal_power_control(false);
}

void loop() {
}
```

8MHzで動作可能なアプリに限定されますが、相当電力を下げることができます。

Comment: 教えていただきありがとうございます。さっそく試してみます。